# Error I got while trying to make json work in a jsp page . How to debug this?

Tags: java, json, jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" import="net.sf.json.JSONArray" %>

 <%
  JSONArray arrayObj=new JSONArray();
   arrayObj.add("MCA");
   arrayObj.add("Amit Kumar");
   arrayObj.add("19-12-1986");
   arrayObj.add(24);
   arrayObj.add("Scored");
   arrayObj.add(new Double(66.67));
%>
<h2>Array Object is =></h2> <%=arrayObj%>
<br><hr>
<%  for(int i=0;i<arrayObj.size();i++){  %>
          <%=arrayObj.getString(i)%>
<%
  }
%>
```

the error I am getting is this

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. net.sf.json.JSONArray resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 19 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
JSONArray cannot be resolved to a type
16:         <%@ page language="java" import="net.sf.json.JSONArray" %>
17:  
18:         <%
19:         JSONArray arrayObj=new JSONArray();
20:         arrayObj.add("MCA");
21:          arrayObj.add("Amit Kumar");
22:          arrayObj.add("19-12-1986");


An error occurred at line: 19 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
JSONArray cannot be resolved to a type
16:         <%@ page language="java" import="net.sf.json.JSONArray" %>
17:  
18:         <%
19:         JSONArray arrayObj=new JSONArray();
20:         arrayObj.add("MCA");
21:          arrayObj.add("Amit Kumar");
22:          arrayObj.add("19-12-1986");
```

How to debug this error ? I have downloaded the Json library and have put it in Tomcat/webapps/star/WEB-INF/lib.

Where star is the folder that contains the jsp page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the JSON library is not there where you think it is, or the JAR file of the JSON library which you've downloaded simply doesn't contain that class. Investigate the JAR file using a ZIP or RAR tool. There should be a `net/sf/json/JSONArray.class` file inside the JAR. If it is missing, then you probably downloaded the wrong library.

Comment: *Unrelated to the problem: the JSP is the wrong place for this job. You may find the examples in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/update-current-page-with-a-servlet) useful.*

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem it is solved after i placed json libraries in WEB-INF\lib folder
If you are using eclipse it helps to clean build once.

--Kiran.Kumar

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem, make sure you Download JSONLibraries and place it into Tomcat's lib directory . Also **restart the server** before executing your jsp file.