# Why am I not able to create object of JSONArray?

Tags: java, json, jsp

I am a fresher in java and jsp and I am using json. I have imported json library in my jsp page. `<%@ page import ="net.sf.json.JSONArray" %>`. but when I am creating the object of `net.sf.json.JSONArray array=new net.sf.json.JSONArray();` an error is thrown. I don't know what is wrong. please help me. 
I have also tried `JSONArray array=new JSONArray()` but this is also not working. I am stuck here. plz plz help me.

Comment: Provide your json string. Your json string might have errors

Comment: @Pasupathi sorry to being so dumb but i am totally new in json. can u make it more clear please

Comment: @varun, but can you be more clearer? what error are you getting?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, If you have a Json String then you can create JsonObject or JsonArray. You can refer this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package, the error message is misleading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error I got while trying to make json work in a jsp page . How to debug this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314976/error-i-got-while-trying-to-make-json-work-in-a-jsp-page-how-to-debug-this)

Comment: @singhakash the question you are talking about I have already checked it .the jar file I have downloaded have this class- net/sf/json/JSONArray.class. Still I am getting the error.

Comment: @varun what IDE you are using try clean and build

Comment: @ singhakash eclipse . cleaned and build,  still same problem bro